# Underestimate an improper integral

Tags: integration

Let $f$ a positive function with a singularity at M.
Is it possible to put
$\int_{a}^{M/2}f(x)dx\leq \int_{a}^{M}f(x)dx$? The integral $\int_{a}^{M/2}f(x)dx$ is finite and then we can put   $\int_{a}^{M/2}f(x)dx=c$ , whith $c$ is a positive constant.

Comment: If $f$ is positive, then clearly $\int_a^b{f(x)dx} \leq \int_a^d{f(x)dx}$ for $b\leq d$, so its true if $M$ is positive

Comment: $M$,$a$,$b$ and $c$ are positive real numbers.

Comment: Then your estimation is correct

Comment: To get the constant $c$  strictly positive is it sufficient to assume that $f\not\equiv 0$ in $[a,M/2]$ ?

Comment: Yes it is, since if the integrand is positive, the integral is itself positive